# How exactly does the ripple effect source code work?

Tags: java, android

I recently found the following code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class RippleViewCreator extends FrameLayout {
    private float duration = 150;
    private int frameRate = 15;
    private float speed = 1;
    private float radius = 0;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private float endRadius = 0;
    private float rippleX = 0;
    private float rippleY = 0;
    private int width = 0;
    private int height = 0;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private int touchAction;

    public RippleViewCreator(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public RippleViewCreator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public RippleViewCreator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (isInEditMode())
            return;

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.control_highlight_color));
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        setWillNotDraw(true);
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        setClickable(true);
    }

    public static void addRippleToView(View v) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
        int index = -1;
        if (parent != null) {
            index = parent.indexOfChild(v);
            parent.removeView(v);
        }
        RippleViewCreator rippleViewCreator = new RippleViewCreator(v.getContext());
        rippleViewCreator.setLayoutParams(v.getLayoutParams());
        if (index == -1)
            parent.addView(rippleViewCreator, index);
        else
            parent.addView(rippleViewCreator);
        rippleViewCreator.addView(v);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

        if (radius > 0 && radius < endRadius) {
            canvas.drawCircle(rippleX, rippleY, radius, paint);
            if (touchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event) {
        rippleX = event.getX();
        rippleY = event.getY();

        touchAction = event.getAction();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

                radius = 1;
                endRadius = Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(width - rippleX, rippleX), rippleY), height - rippleY);
                speed = endRadius / duration * frameRate;
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (radius < endRadius) {
                            radius += speed;
                            paint.setAlpha(90 - (int) (radius / endRadius * 90));
                            handler.postDelayed(this, frameRate);
                        } else if (getChildAt(0) != null) {
                            getChildAt(0).performClick();
                        }
                    }
                }, frameRate);
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                endRadius = Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(width - rippleX, rippleX), rippleY), height - rippleY);
                paint.setAlpha(90);
                radius = endRadius / 3;
                invalidate();
                return true;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                if (rippleX < 0 || rippleX > width || rippleY < 0 || rippleY > height) {
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    touchAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL;
                    break;
                } else {
                    invalidate();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        invalidate();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public final void addView(@NonNull View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        //limit one view
        if (getChildCount() > 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(this.getClass().toString() + " can only have one child.");
        }
        super.addView(child, index, params);
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me how exactly does this ripple effect code work because I been trying to understand it for at least a day now and I still can't understand how it exactly work.

**Precisely** I don't understand:

```
public static void addRippleToView(View v) {
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
    int index = -1;
    if (parent != null) {
        index = parent.indexOfChild(v);
        parent.removeView(v);
    }
    RippleViewCreator rippleViewCreator = new RippleViewCreator(v.getContext());
    rippleViewCreator.setLayoutParams(v.getLayoutParams());
    if (index == -1)
        parent.addView(rippleViewCreator, index);
    else
        parent.addView(rippleViewCreator);
    rippleViewCreator.addView(v);
}
```

Comment: What exactly presents you a problem?

Comment: hang on I ll edit the code to clarify

Comment: Great idea. Please be as detailed as possible.

Comment: I just edited the question and that is the snippet of code that I don't understand what is going on. on the bottom, it said index == -1 and then parent.addView(rippleViewCreator,index) However, if parent does not exist than how can it add that view?

Comment: @Wowzer, I agree with you, IMHO there are other bugs in this code. However it's not clear what is your question. Have you tested this code, and it DOES work for you, and you're only trying to understand why and how it works? If it doesn't work, then please rephrase your question and also indicate what do you expect and what do you experience instead

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to add that the code definitely work. My ultimate goal is to try to understand how exactly does android effects get created. So the code above what I am asking is how does that code basically function. In other word, how does the ripple effect java code may function. My confusion lies in the fact that I am very confused on how the ripple effect is achieve with the code above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know *if* this class actually works, but if *does*, it's guess like this:

This custom view subclasses FrameLayout, which means it expects to have a child view.  So you would declare it in your view XML and give it a child to place within its bounds.

When it receives a touch event in onTouchEVent, it draws an animated ripple effect, which would appear behind the view it contains.

The developer may also tell this RippleViewCreator to render a ripple effect behind a specific view it contains by calling addRippleToView.  It looks like this method removes the targeted child view from the view hierarchy, wraps it in yet another RippleViewCreator, and adds *that* back into its own view hierarchy for a ripple animation.

Crazy stuff, man.

Comment: Hey yah what I found kinda odd was that the if index == -1 then parent.addView(RippleViewCreator,index). However, the only way for the index to be -1 based on that part of the code I highlighted above is that if the parents are null. So if parents are null how can it adds the view? I guess index could be -1 if that view does not exist. However if the view does not exist than the v.getparent method is not valid either. So I am really confuse

Comment: The javadoc for getParent makes no mention that it can ever return null.

Comment: oh WOW thanks for the answer. now that is interesting but if not null then  what does getParent return then if that view doesn't have a parent  of that view is null?

Comment: The javadoc says that getParent can return a ViewParent, and a ViewParent just assumes the *responsibility* of what a parent needs to do, which is itself not necessarily a view itself.

Comment: Gee thanks but I still don't get it. So lets said that I don't supply it with a view right? then would that getParent method not work? Also you said that ViewParent not necessarily have to be a view. I thought that viewParent has to be a viewgroup in order to add other view child?

Comment: The ViewParent could be something outside your view hierarchy (maybe a window container for the whole thing?).  The point is that detail is abstracted away from you when calling that method.

Comment: And if you call addRippleToView with null, you will certainly crash with NullPointerException.  It seems you have to call it with an actual child view.  Too bad there's no javadoc for this.